# Unable to display table data from array using D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```js
var data = [
  ["First Name", "Last Name", "Job Title", "Favorite Color", "Wars or Trek?", "Porn Name", "Date of Birth", "Dream Vacation City", "GPA", "Arbitrary Data"],
  ["James,Matman", "Chief Sandwich Eater", "Lettuce Green", "Trek,Digby Green", "January 13, 1979", "Gotham City", "3.1", "RBX-12"],
  ["The", "Tick", "Crimefighter Sorta", "Blue", "Wars", "John Smith", "July 19, 1968", "Athens", "N/A", "Edlund, Ben (July 1996)."]
];

var sortAscending = true;

var titles = data[0];

var table = d3.select('#page-wrap')
  .append('table');

var headers = table.append('thead')
  .append('tr')
  .selectAll('th')
  .data(titles)
  .enter()
  .append('th')
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .on('click', function(d) {
    headers.attr('class', 'header');

    if (sortAscending) {
      rows.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b[d] < a[d];
      });
      sortAscending = false;
      this.className = 'aes';
    } else {
      rows.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b[d] > a[d];
      });
      sortAscending = true;
      this.className = 'des';
    }

  });

var rows = table.append('tbody')
  .selectAll('tr')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('tr');

rows.selectAll('td')
  .data(function(d) {
    return titles.map(function(k) {
      return {
        'value': d[k],
        'name': k
      };
    });
  })
  .enter()
  .append('td')
  .attr('data-th', function(d) {
    return d.name;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });
```

```css
 * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
 body {
   font: 14px/1.4 Georgia, Serif;
 }
 #page-wrap {
   margin: 50px;
 }
 p {
   margin: 20px 0;
 }
 /* 
 Generic Styling, for Desktops/Laptops 
 */
 table {
   width: 100%;
   border-collapse: collapse;
 }
 /* Zebra striping */
 tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
   background: #eee;
 }
 th {
   background: #333;
   color: white;
   font-weight: bold;
   cursor: s-resize;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: 3% center;
 }
 td,
 th {
   padding: 6px;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   text-align: left;
 }
 th.des:after {
   content: "\21E9";
 }
 th.aes:after {
   content: "\21E7";
 }
 /* 
 Max width before this PARTICULAR table gets nasty
 This query will take effect for any screen smaller than 760px
 and also iPads specifically.
 */
 @media only screen and (max-width: 760px),
 (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
   /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
   table,
   thead,
   tbody,
   th,
   td,
   tr {
     display: block;
   }
   /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
   thead tr {
     position: absolute;
     top: -9999px;
     left: -9999px;
   }
   tr {
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
   }
   td {
     /* Behave  like a "row" */
     border: none;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
     position: relative;
     padding-left: 50%;
   }
   td:before {
     /* Now like a table header */
     position: absolute;
     /* Top/left values mimic padding */
     top: 6px;
     left: 6px;
     width: 45%;
     padding-right: 10px;
     white-space: nowrap;
   }
   /*
  Label the data
  */
   td:before {
     content: attr(data-th)": ";
     font-weight: bold;
     width: 6.5em;
     display: inline-block;
   }
 }
 /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
 @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
   body {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     width: 320px;
   }
 }
 /* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
 @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
   body {
     width: 495px;
   }
 }
```

```html
<div id="page-wrap"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Hello I am new to D3. I am really stuck at a point to draw a d3 table using my dataset. Please help me. I am able to get only the headers but no data for the headers in the table rows. I don't know what error I am doing in this. Please suggest me something. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the last bit from

```
rows.selectAll('td')
  .data(function(d) {
    return titles.map(function(k) {
      return {
        'value': d[k],
        'name': k
      };
    });
  })
  .enter()
  .append('td')
  .attr('data-th', function(d) {
    return d.name;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });
```

to -

```
rows.selectAll('td')
  .data(function(d) {
    return titles.map(function(k,i) {
      return {
        'value': d[i],
        'name': k
      };
    });
  })
  .enter()
  .append('td')
  .attr('data-th', function(d) {
    return d.name;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });
```

'titles' is an array; you will need the indices to access each data-entry.

Comment: Thank you so much Tanu for your answer. It works like charm and as per my need but I am getting a extra row again displaying my header elements in the first row. How to avoid it. Actually I have two rows in table data but still there are 3 rows created with repeating header elements in that first row.. What am I doing wrong in this??? Please tell me. : )

Comment: That is because the data passed to row contains all three rows.... You can slice the data array before passing to rows object.    var data2 = data.slice(1, data.length);
var rows = table.append('tbody')
  .selectAll('tr')
  .data(data2)
  .enter()
  .append('tr');

Comment: Ok I got it... I am new to this field So unknown about the .slice method. It will take the value from 2nd row of data till the total length of my data and save it as another variable. Got it. Thank you so much Tanu. : ))